# How to write a skew symmetric matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I want to write a programme in R to get a specific matrix from null matrix using the row and col function.
I have to create a 6*6 matrix as follows.

```
A=matrix(rep(0,36),nrow=6)
B=col(A)-row(A)
B
```

I used the function row(A)-col(A)
and got some skew symmetric matrix with the diagonal as 0, How do I proceed now?

Comment: What is this specific matrix? Show us your final expected output.

Comment: Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need something like this?

```
sym_matrix <- function(n) {
  A=matrix(0,nrow=n, ncol = n)
  A[abs(row(A) - col(A)) == 1] <- 1
  A
}

sym_matrix(4)    

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    0    1    0    0
#[2,]    1    0    1    0
#[3,]    0    1    0    1
#[4,]    0    0    1    0

sym_matrix(6)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    0    1    0    0    0    0
#[2,]    1    0    1    0    0    0
#[3,]    0    1    0    1    0    0
#[4,]    0    0    1    0    1    0
#[5,]    0    0    0    1    0    1
#[6,]    0    0    0    0    1    0
```